# Что означает запись using TasksInfo = map<TaskStatus, int>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Не могу найти нормальных примеров использование `using наименование = ...`, нахожу просто `using`.Что означает эта запись `using TasksInfo = map<TaskStatus, int>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Определение псевдонима типа. То, что раньше было

```
typedef map<TaskStatus, int> TasksInfo;
```

Т.е. теперь, чтоб не писать длинно

```
map<TaskStatus, int> m;
```

можно писать короче:

```
TasksInfo m;
```

Примерно так...

Comment: а пример с using надо бы наверное добавить в ответ)

Comment: @Maggot, такой пример уже написан в вопросе, а ответ содержит обяснение  того, что это значит

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ответ должен быть понятен, упоминания using тут не будет лишним)